# Trying to create a Master Plan. Dates and duration of some projects change when inserted as a Sub-project

Tags: ms-office, project, project-management, ms-project

Trying to make a Master Plan on MS Project.

Some sub-projects were inserted with no issues, but for other sub-projects both the **work effort and Duration change.** 
Is there a reason for this? If you see the images below, for instance the overall Work effort decreases from 225 to 182 and duration changes as well.

1. Project Plan
   [image: Project Plan]
2. Project Plan inserted as sub-project
   [image: Project Plan inserted as sub-project]

If I try to change this in the inserted Sub-project, then the calculations are off. For instance if i put work to 3 days (resource at 80%), the duration comes as 4.62 rather than 3.75. Even if i put the resource at 100%, the work and duration still don't match.

Could someone please help me with this?

Link to Plan - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgjIwYECazJVkUx7-SG8ek-7xq0b?e=C4PtzQ

Comment: It is a better practice to clearly identify and define the each dependency and predecessor to avoid and constrains.

Answer (score 0):

Effort and time estimations need to be clearly identified as sub-tasks through each and every dependencies. In your plan try to customize each sub-task's resource and effort estimations. As you know start and end dates may be changed as of the scheduling methods. (Automatic or Manual).
It's better to use the main task first and then include the sub-tasks. Then arrange the scheduling as Auto schedule by selecting a specific starting date column. See this document it may help you. [Here](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/project/manual-schedule-versus-automatic-schedule-in-project-2013/#:%7E:text=Auto%20Schedule%3A%20Project%20calculates%20task,dates%2C%20and%20specifying%20them%20later.).